# Manga where pregnant women get bitten by giant mosquitoes that had drills for mouths

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read, maybe 9 or 10 years ago, a manga in which everyone was in a town that was cursed by spirals. Some of the scenes are as follows...

There was one where pregnant women were getting "bitten" by giant mosquitoes that had drills for mouths, then the women would give birth to fully cognitive babies who wanted to be back in the womb.

There was a scene near the end where a giant spiral hole was in the center of the town and the main characters had to go down to the bottom.

It would probably be considered body-horror in genre.

What is the name? I am pretty sure the author is Junji Ito.

Comment: @Lexible yeah... it was a pretty crazy book... it was good though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [*Uzumaki*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uzumaki) by Junto Ito.

> The series tells the story of the citizens of Kurouzu-cho, a fictional city which is plagued by a supernatural curse involving spirals. The story for Uzumaki originated when Ito attempted to write a story about people living in a very long terraced house, and he was inspired to use a spiral shape to achieve the desired length. Ito believes the horror of Uzumaki is effective due to its subversion of symbols which are positively portrayed in Japanese media, and its theme of protagonists struggling against a mysterious force stronger than themselves. Uzumaki continues to receive critical acclaim, deemed by many as Ito's magnum opus

The scene with the mosquitos is in part #7

> [image]

Comment: Incidentally, this is an amazing, if disturbing, work. The live action adaptation is surprisingly good as well.

Comment: So the questioner was looking for a manga about spirals by Junji Ito, and the answer turned out to be the manga "Spiral" by Junji Ito?

Comment: @Showsni - I would imagine that the problem here is that they seem to have started reading the Manga about five or six issues in, hence why the pregnancy thing (which is actually a pretty small event) is so clear in their mind. Since they started quite far in, if they Google 'Spirals' by Junto Ito, they'll see a bunch of stuff that's unfamiliar

Comment: Nah... @Showsni I just remembered that one scene because it was the most crazy, to me at least

Comment: @Showsni Yeah... I didn't know Uzumaki meant spiral so... but know I do. Thanks!